# PHP - validate mustache template

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

How do I validate a mustache template string in PHP? For example, if I pass

```
Hi {{#name}}{{name}}{{/name}}{{^name}}guest{{/name}}
```

and the validator should return valid, but if I pass

```
Hi {{#name}}{{name}}{{/name}}{{^name}}guest
```

it should return invalid.

**Note** I'd rather this to be done fully in PHP with no `Mustache_Engine` or any other 3rd party dependency.

Comment: short answer: write your own Mustache Engine. (tip: it's easier and less error prone to just use an existing library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to correctly validate all valid mustache templates without building a mustache parser. There is no regular expression shortcut. You need an actual parser.

If you're okay with some false negatives (and some false positives) you could build something to validate a subset of them. Or you can build a proper parser. But your best bet is to use mustache.php to parse it, as indicated in other answers.

Why are you trying to do this without any dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Just compile it:

```
function validate($template) {
    $m = new Mustache_Engine;
    try {
        $m->getParser()->parse($m->getTokenizer()->scan($template));
        $valid = true;
    } catch (Mustache_Exception_SyntaxException $e) {
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Comment: I'll update my comment, but I do not want to use any other packages.

Comment: Then please update your question once again and show what you have tried so far.